# Integrate a Twitter API in to Google Maps (GEO / Hashtag)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, twitter, google-geocoding-api

I am a little bit a newbie if it comes to programming. The case is as following: I want to make a Google Map (API) where I can view Tweets on basis of a hashtag / geocoding / place.

I am able to make the Google map but when it comes to loading the Twitter API as an overlay I got stuck. I have looked at the internet for several tutorial but I could not find any which helps me out.

Can someone pinpoint what steps I have to take to build this Google map.

Comment: Did you end up making a service?  I'm working on one right now for fun.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this article](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun.html). At the end there is a link to an example that searches twitter and displays the results on a map.

Comment: this answer is no more helpful.